# Add Swagger schema for a uploaded file on Net Core 3

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger, swagger-ui

I have an action like that:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Process(IFormFile file)
{
}
```

My file is a Json (MyJsonClass). Would be possible to show MyJsonClass on Swagger ? How?

Thanks

Comment: what do you mean by show MyJsonClass on swagger?

Comment: I would like to show how JSON should be (a sample?), like is showed in my return when I did that : [ProducesResponseType(typeof(MyReturnApiJson), 200)]

Comment: oh so you need that json to be a sample value display for this action in swagger ui?

Comment: That should work I think, or a link to a sample file if posible

Answer (score 1):

Here is a good post that explains your need solution, although it is not done with a .json file.

https://mattfrear.com/2015/04/21/generating-swagger-example-responses-with-swashbuckle/